# Selecting columns from database if column exist

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

i have a attandence table which is altered every day by adding a new column by current day
now i want to see attendence by month i dont know whether all these column exist if make query for select all the column by adding full month days

```
 BM_query = @"[" + st.m + "/1" + "/" + st.y + "] ," + "[" + st.m + "/2" + "/" + st.y + "] ," +
                           "[" + st.m + "/3" + "/" + st.y + "] ," + "[" + st.m + "/4" + "/" + st.y + "] ," +
                           "[" + st.m + "/5" + "/" + st.y + "] ," + "[" + st.m + "/6" + "/" + st.y + "] ," +
                           "[" + st.m + "/7" + "/" + st.y + "] ," + "[" + st.m + "/8" + "/" + st.y + "] ," +
                           "[" + st.m + "/9" + "/" + st.y + "] ," + "[" + st.m + "/10" + "/" + st.y + "] ," +
                           "[" + st.m + "/11" + "/" + st.y + "] ," + "[" + st.m + "/12" + "/" + st.y + "] ," +
                           "[" + st.m + "/13" + "/" + st.y + "] ," + "[" + st.m + "/14" + "/" + st.y + "] ," +
                           "[" + st.m + "/15" + "/" + st.y + "] ," + "[" + st.m + "/16" + "/" + st.y + "] ," +
                           "[" + st.m + "/17" + "/" + st.y + "] ," + "[" + st.m + "/18" + "/" + st.y + "] ," +
                           "[" + st.m + "/19" + "/" + st.y + "] ," + "[" + st.m + "/20" + "/" + st.y + "] ," +
                           "[" + st.m + "/21" + "/" + st.y + "] ," + "[" + st.m + "/22" + "/" + st.y + "] ," +
                           "[" + st.m + "/23" + "/" + st.y + "] ," + "[" + st.m + "/24" + "/" + st.y + "] ," +
                           "[" + st.m + "/25" + "/" + st.y + "] ," + "[" + st.m + "/26" + "/" + st.y + "] ," +
                           "[" + st.m + "/27" + "/" + st.y + "] ," + "[" + st.m + "/28" + "/" + st.y + "] ," +
                           "[" + st.m + "/29" + "/" + st.y + "] ," + "[" + st.m + "/30" + "/" + st.y + "] " ;



query = "select Roll_No , Student_Name, " + BM_query + " from [" + textBox2.Text + "_attandence] ";
```

if the column not exist it show invalid column name like 2/7/2017 .... and so on
can i ignore these column that are not exist and continue to next and next ..

Comment: Seems like the worst table design ever...

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: You're going to need to check for the columns' existence _before_ you construct the query.  But this is just a taste of the pain that awaits you with a table design like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve the names of the table columns with a query like this:

```
select COLUMN_NAME
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'attendance'
```

and then loop through the results to construct your query.

But seriously, you should really go back to the drawing board on this one.  This table goes against everything a RDBMS stands for.  What are you going to do when you hit the maximum number of columns allowed for the table?

What are you going to do when you only want to see a month's worth of records?  Or when you want to add up the attendance between two dates?  You aren't going to be able to leverage any of the functionality built into SQL.  You're going to have to construct all your queries by building up strings, and everything you try to do will be slow and brittle.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DataTable populated with data from your EVER expanding table then you can check to see if the columns exists.

```
table.Columns.Contains("ColumnName");
```

Answer (score 0):

This work fine gives all columnn names that exist and neglect other

```
 DECLARE @dd INT;
 SET @dd = 1;

 DECLARE @tmp Varchar(5)
 SET @tmp = '';

 DECLARE @have Varchar(max)
 SET @have = '';

 WHILE @dd <= 31
 BEGIN 
 IF COL_LENGTH('test','2/' + CONVERT(varchar, @dd) + '/2017') IS NOT NULL
 set @have=@have+'2/' + CONVERT(varchar, @dd) + '/2017 ,';
    SET @dd = @dd + 1;

 END;

 PRINT @have;
 GO
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following query

```
select COLUMN_NAME
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'your table name'
```